# How to split one row into 12 based on month in SQL?

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

I have 2 tables. Table A and Table B. I need to create table C. Table B is a time series table with one record for each day. I am using Azure SQL
I would like to Split the row into each individual month as below:

Table A

```
StartDate     EndDate
2018-02-12   2019-02-12
```

Table B

```
Date        Day       Month      Year
2018-01-01  Monday    Jan          2018
2018-02-02  Tuesday    Feb         2018
:
:
2019-12-31  Tuesday    Dec         2019
```

Output

```
Table C
StartDate   EndDate      Month   
2018-02-12  2018-02-28   Feb
2018-03-01  2018-03-31   March
:
:
2019-02-01  2019-02-12   Feb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by grouping TableB and using TableA as a filter.

```
select
     min(date) as StartDate
    ,max(date) as EndDate
    ,Month
from TableB
where date >= (select StartDate from TableA)
and date <= (select EndDate from TableA)
group by Month,Year
```

When you have more rows in tableB (additional column `id`):

```
select
     min(date) as StartDate
    ,max(date) as EndDate
    ,Month
    ,a.id
from TableB b
join TableA a
    on b.Date between a.StartDate and a.EndDate
group by id,Month,Year
```

Comment: Yes this solution worked for me when i put a where condition in subqueries (select StartDate from TableA where txn number = 1).. How can i get the same output for all the records in the data?   When i run your query without where condition i get the following error:"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: In your example there is only one row in TableA, if there are multiple rows this will fail as you mentioned date >= (select StartDate from TableA). The subquery must return 1 row in other case the condigion doesn't make sense. To resolve this you can use min and max values -> date >= (select Min(StartDate) from TableA), but it's hard to advise you when I don't know excatly your case.

Comment: I added one more query.